# Allocating huge amount of relatively small objects in Java

Tags: java, memory-management

What is the best way (least memory consuption/swapping) to allocate memory for multiple (couple of million) small objects (containing 3 to 6 Doubles, maybe a String) in Java?

I can think of three different strategies:

1. *Naive:* Do nothing special, let the virtual machine handle the memory.
2. *Factory-style:* Create objects via factory class. Factory creates
   multiple objects at once (thousand or so per batch) and handles
   object recycling (no need to create new ones if used ones are available).
3. *Array-style:* Store data in basic arrays. Access data via index numbers.

**Clarification:**
The target platform has very low memory (512 megabytes).

Comment: None of those options actually involves "bulk" memory allocation.

Comment: And just to clarify: Are you talking about the Oracle JDK, Android, or some other embeded jdk? For the Oracle JDK option 1 is the best.

Comment: O'Reilly book [_Java Performance Tuning_](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html) suggests using a thing called `PoolManager`, but that information seems to be 13 years old.

Comment: @MTilsted not correct: an object needs 12 bytes, ineependent of the VM, therfore option 3 saves much memory, see my answer

Comment: True, but option 3 trade ram for processor power. Since the requirement just changed to a "low memory solution" option 3 might be the best.

Comment: @MTilsted ok i was the last who read the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is of course the most memory effective.

Example:

```
class Point {
  double x;
  double y;
}
```

Needs 12 for the Point object and 2 * 8 for x and y = 28 bytes
Point[]: Using an array of Point objects: 28 bytes per point (and 16 for the array itself)

Now as 
`int[] xycoords`: order: x1,y1,x2,y2,.....xn,yn:

That needs 16 bytes per x,y coordinate. which is 57% compared to class Point

Imagine you have build navigation system and you can only store half of europe because of sub optimal data representation.

**But**
Although Option 3 saves memory, I recomend to use the obejct approach for the first version. The array approach has much more probability of coding errors, especially 
for complex algorithms.

Once version 1 works (and hopefully you have unit tests) you can implement v2 using the array approach. and check with your unit tests that all still works.

Comment: I know this depends on the JVM implementation, but afaik arrays are usually stored in contiguous memory blocks. When you're trying to allocate a large portion of your heap at once you may run into issues, especially when using a non-compacting GC. Just something to keep in mind when evaluating the different options.

Comment: @JohannesR interesting because I use this solution in a current embedded java project. Have you more infos on that, e.g How Androids Dalvik VM behaves?

Comment: I have zero experience with Dalvik. I think generally this issue is solved by falling back to a different, compacting collector (I have to admit I forgot about that), so in the end its "just" a performance issue. And if you create this array once in the beginning, there's (almost) no heap fragmentation, and therefore no issue at all. But if you have to "extend" the array regularly or/and if you have big heaps which take long to collect, this could have a noticable impact on performance.

Comment: now its clear, i create that array once at start up, and never change it.

Comment: I accept this one as the best, although what I did was somewhat different... I used the dumb Object approach during alpha phase (1. Naive), and when I got that working I re-factored code to use a Factory class (2. Factory-style), and when I got that working I re-factored again the whole thing in pure C with Java bindings.

Comment: interesting, what kind of project/ device?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. For sure. A couple of million objects is nothing special, and the VM can easily manage that.

Option 2 probably won't make a difference in memory usage, and number 3 is the worst option available. See Item 55 from Effective Java, 2nd edition.

Comment: No 3 is the most memory efficient, it saves 57% of memory, see my answer. Having millions of objects make a difference in embedded systems.

Comment: Who was talking about embedded systems? I was assuming a general purpose application, since no where was embedded mentioned. Even the very low memory, which I don't consider low btw, was added later. And I don't see how it's relevant to state that I don't have much experience in embedded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming worst-case (6 Double), everything should fit in memory.

**Explanation**:
You say Double and not double. Wrapper overhead is 16 bytes, if I remember correclty.
This means 16 (wrapper overhead) + 8 (double value) = 24 bytes per Double.
For 6 Double times 2 millions : ~ 274 Mo

**Consequence**: Go for Option 1.

If want want some optimisations hints :

- Go for double instead of Double.
- Without going with basic
  arrays due to overhead, try instead BitSet from Java or better (lower
  overhead I think) library like Colt with its [BitVector](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html). This
  could help in optimising space, without sacrifying performance.
- Try anything you think of, but benchmark it. In case it does not work
  as expected, you'll learn from the experience!